# Set Description, Draft and Permalink using Blogger API with PHP

Tags: php, blogger, google-blogger-api

I really need your help with this matter. I'm looking for a solution for about 3 months now, but really the Blogger API is not easy to deal with because Blogger don't even provide examples.

I can create and publish new posts with PHP script and I have done all things, but I can't set the Post's description, permalink, or even making the new post as draft.

The following is a piece of my code that creating the post.

```
<?php

    $mypost = new Google_Post();
    $mypost->setTitle('My Post Title');
    $mypost->setContent('This is My Content');
    $mypost->setLabels( array( 'News','Weather', 'Media' ) );
    $mypost->setCustomMetaData('My_CUSTOM_META_DATA' . time()); // Nothing changed
    $mypost->setcustomMetaData('This is the description for you');  //Nothing Changed
    $mypost->setDescription('New Description');   // Nothing Changed
    $mypost->setUrl('testseturl');   // Nothing Changed
    $mypost->setPublished('2021-08-27T23:07:00-07:00');  // Worked as Schedule post

    $data = $blogger->posts->insert('My BlogID', $mypost); 

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

As you can see I can't set the permalink and I tried several thing such as adding the full URL, and also adding only the custom permalink text + html, but I failed.

I tried also the description several times, but every time I found the description's post empty.

Also I can' set the post as Draft and I have to do this manually from the blog itself.

Blogger doesn't provide any help docs for PHP, and the [new Beta client library on github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) is for all Google products and I wasn't able to use it. I use the library Google API PHP Client 0.6.7 [found here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-php-client/downloads) although it's deprecated.

The only topic I found in [this blog](http://gayanonline.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-api-v3-with-php-using-blogger.html), and it's the same code that I use, but he didn't mentioned anything about permalink, draft, or description.

Please help me as you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## permalink

Unfortunately there is no way to set custom permalink to the posts using Blogger api, even the official "[Try this API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert)" tool don't have this feature, your code is fine it's just Blogger don't support it.

## custom description

I don't think there is a way to add custom description as well, `setDescription` is not a valid method, you can check all the supported methods [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Blogger/Post.php)

## draft post

to create a post draft you can do it like this

```php
$optParams = array('isDraft' => true);
$data = $blogger->posts->insert('My BlogID', $mypost, $optParams);
```

Comment: 1- Thanks for your reply. I didn't know there is now way to set the custom permalink using Blogger API, but what setUrl() actually do.

2- About the setDescription() it's exist as function on the library I have. In this path "../GoogleClientAPI/src/contrib/Google_BloggerService.php" I found the following code:

  public function setDescription( $description) {
    $this->description = $description;
  }
  public function getDescription() {
    return $this->description;
  }

Comment: 3- I tried your code , but I get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(insert) unknown parameter: 'isDraft'' in ...\Project Path\GoogleClientApi\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php:111 Stack trace: #0 ...\Project Path\GoogleClientApi\src\contrib\Google_BloggerService.php(292): Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #1 ...\Project Path\\testapi.php(978): Google_PostsServiceResource->insert('BlogID...', Object(Google_Post), Array) #2 {main} thrown in ...\Project Path\GoogleClientApi\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php on line 111

Comment: `setUrl` should be the method that sets the custom url but it's not working! the errors you are getting because you are using an old package which is [deprecated](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-php-client/downloads), you can find the latest versions [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases)

Comment: Thanks Bouh for your Support. One last question if you don't mind. Can I use the same code with the new package? or I have to know the methods name of the new package from somewhere?.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to make some changes because the two versions are bit different

Comment: Many Thanks Bouh for you helpful replies. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I want to let you know that I have modified my code to use the new version and now I can set the post as draft. Thanks again Bouh.